# Is possible to combine rest-api and angular profiles on Grails?

Tags: rest, grails, grails-3.1

I'm going to start a new project that has two front ends,  a mobile APP and a Web Application.

I was thinking about creating a "rest-api" grails application and consume this "api" from the mobile apps.

But, for the WebApp,  is it possible to create a new "angular" Grails app that uses as model the previously  generated "rest-api" Grails application and ovoids me to "re-implement the wheel (model)"?

Any articles/documentation how that could be accomplish?

Thanks in advance.

JD Evora

Comment: Put your shared domain classes into a plugin, use the plugin in both applications. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the domain you already have in the new rest api, nothing changes. You may want to add the @Resource annotations.

If there is another app that uses this same domain, I would put in a plugin(as @Joshua suggested), we currently do it for clients  which have both admin/cms and final user applications.

In our company,we are currently developing 3 projects with an idea I believe will fit well to your needs, or may help someone else who is starting a similar project

**We organized the apps this way:**

- We've created a grails app with rest-api profile
- We've created a grunt/bower/npm project(you could use **yoo angular generator**, but It had more than we needed)
- We've created an android and and ios apps

**Advantages we've seen:**

- The angular application calls the same methods as the mobile apps, there is only one controller, one service, one grails app
- The web apps is pure JS and CSS and runs smoothly in the serve(**npm
  install serve**)
- You can deploy the web app  in any CDN like Amazon Cloud Front and be able to handle a big demand, and you can deploy it quickly

Just in case you don't know, but with grunt and bower you can replace assets pipeline automation.

Hope it helps you!